# Spring and GAE : ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

I'm now to Spring, GAE and Java in general. I'm trying to use a web app I made for Spring and to which I added GAE support afterwards. I went through a lot of problems but now I'm stuck on this one.

`Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:138)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)
    ... 25 more
Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@327124af{/,C:\Users\SolarBear\Desktop\myProject\myProjectService2\war}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@3b19e583: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Error starting handlers
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:138)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)
    ... 25 more
Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:259)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:138)
Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Aug 2, 2012 3:52:40 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin`

I realize that my context is not initialized properly but since this is managed directly by Spring, I have no idea how to solve this. I'm not sure what information I should be giving you, so here are some important files.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
<!-- 
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value/>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

-->

</web-app>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sixisolution.togethrservice" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the config files I see here. Everything looks good. Exception says an Initialize error, sometime it happens where a properties file or a constructor failed to Initialize. Can you verify based on the config file here, is this

`<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`

configured and ready to go?? I have my properties folder under src that gets compiled to the output directory.

The other thing that is in the stacktrace is DefaultListableBeanFactory exception initialization problem. Please verify if you have the correct versions of spring Jar files in your classpath.

Comment: You set me on the right path! After messing around a bit, I moved my Spring .JAR files from the Bootstrap entries to the User Entries in my Eclipse project (Run -> Run Configurations, then select my web app, then Classpath and moved the JARs to the bottom section) and it works. It seems either this or the actual order of inclusion mattered. Thank you so much!